# How much percent of the total Euro Zone Euros was artificially added through systems like QE this century?

Tags: european-union, monetary-policy, central-bank, monetary-union

Until 2018, the ECB 'printed' [€ 2,500,000,000,000](https://www.bbc.com/news/business-46552147) (2.5 trillion) through [quantitative easing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantitative_easing), and then it proceeded to add [€ 20,000,000,000](https://www.cnbc.com/2019/09/13/qe-infinity-economists-believe-ecb-bond-buying-could-run-for-years.html) (20 billion) per month "for as long as necessary", which is still ongoing and equals € 300,000,000,000 until now.

By the end of the year, another € 200,000,000,000 will have been generated, bringing the total to € 3,000,000,000,000 (3 trillion).

Adding the [€ 623,000,000,000](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-eurozone-ecb-anfa/euro-zone-central-banks-printed-billions-of-euros-before-qe-study-idUSKBN0TU15220151211) (623 billion) of ANFA assets the ECB has created, makes a total of € 3,623,000,000,000 (3.6 trillion)

That's more than € 10,000 per capita for every one of the [342 million Euro Zone citizens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eurozone), giving me a rough impression of how much that actually is.

Now what I can't find, is the total sum of all Euros in existence. How much percent of the total Euro supply are these 3.6 trillion artificially created Euros?

Answer (score 1):

According to the European Central Bank, the money supply for Jan 2020 is 13,052 billion euros.

https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/money_credit_banking/monetary_aggregates/html/index.en.html